# What is the strategy to arrange circles on a rectangular card such you can use two identical card to display a tally?

Tags: geometry

Starting with 10 0.5 cm diameter circles on a rectangle of 50 cm by 80 cm rectangle card show exactly 1 to 10 circles using an identical rectangle card to cover the first one. It should be generalisable to square cards with ratio of D diameter to S side length with what is the maximum number displayable? As specified the tally is closer to the easier to do one rather the more guaranteed one which is more a matter of combinations than geometry e.g. show 1 on both cards to show a total of two.

Comment: The card in the problem (before generalizing) isn't square. The title says "two cards" but the question says one. Please edit the question to show us a solution for some small values of $D$ and $S$, for smaller values than $10$ for the number of circles. That will make the problem clearer - more likely to get an answer and more likely to be upvoted.

Comment: The question says two cards- "using an identical rectangle card to cover the first one"  Once you show show from 1-10 on one card then you can do same with the other card

Comment: Also since a particular choice  is a square and you use circles than the absolute sizes don't matter only the ratio and the number of circles since it scales.